# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00201: identifier 'PAYMENT_UPDATE' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, runtime-error

I have a procedure to insert values into one table and update rows of another table. The procedure compiled without any errors. If I manually call it within PL/SQL codes, the tables are updated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE payment_update
      (bId IN number, pType IN varchar2, pAmt IN number )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO payment 
     VALUES (PID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
              bId, 
              pType, 
              (SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL),
              pAmt);
    UPDATE booking 
        SET payment_status = 'FP', 
          paid = pAmt
    WHERE booking_id = bId;
END;
/
```

I am trying to call this stored procedure in a Java class, through the click of a button. The user enters values into a text field of the GUI frame, those values need to be sent to the stored procedure.

This is my Java code -

```
private void payButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    int i = unpaidJTable.getSelectedRow();
    int bookingId =Integer.parseInt(bIdText.getText());
    String pType = pTypeText.getText();
    double pAmt = Double.parseDouble(pAmtText.getText());
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    String paymentUpdateRecord = "{call payment_update(?, ?, ?)}";
    try{
       callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(paymentUpdateRecord);
       callableStatement.setInt(1, bookingId);
       callableStatement.setString(2, pType);
       callableStatement.setDouble(3, pAmt);
       callableStatement.executeUpdate();
       conn.commit();
       System.out.println("Successfully updated!");
   }
    catch(SQLException e){
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
```

On clicking this button, I get an error pasted above as the question. 
Can someone please help me out? I can't figure out what I need to declare.

Comment: Do you connect to the correct schema ?

Comment: Yes, it is corrected to the right schema.

Comment: i think your problem is in your DBMS and not with Java check this link https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21851939/ORA-06550-line-1-column-7-PLS-00201-identifier-%27GET-ALL-USER-SP%27-must-be-declared-ORA-06550-line-1-column-7-PL-SQL-Statement-ignored.html#answer16689689-20

Comment: If you are connecting to a user account that is NOT the owner of the proc, you must create grants and synonyms to the login user account on the item.  All this means is that the user account that your java app is logging into doesn't "know" about the stored proc.

Comment: Have you checked that the user running the code have execute permission on the procedure?  GRANT EXECUTE ON <procedure_name> TO <user>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same problem and figured out the solution.
Actually, When I searched for answer, other post mentioned that 'there could be permission issue'. Which is quit the case here. As a workaround or solution need to do following:
-Drop you SP.
-Recreate SP with Parameter (i.e. your final SP)

You might have created SP first and later did some changes in Parameter section.
See if this helps. However, it did in my case.

Comment: I did same solution but issue is same .It is not resolved

Answer (score 0):

PLS-00201: identifier 'PROC_NAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

I was able to resolve the issue by creating synonym for the procedure.