# Error in calling Stored Proc from Spring JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, stored-procedures

Error in Stored proc execution when called from Java

```
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Override
        public String funcName(String valueId) {
            StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("proc_name");
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("input_id", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.setParameter("input_id", valueId);
            query.execute();
            return "Stored Procedure Exceuted";
        }
    }
```

The value of valueId is present in `query.setParameter("input_id", valueId);`

And I get the following error

```
2020-03-19 20:10:55.904 DEBUG 8684 --- [io-7080-exec-10] o.h.SQL                                  :{call proc_name(?)}
2020-03-19 20:10:56.460  WARN 8684 --- [io-7080-exec-10] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000
2020-03-19 20:10:56.460 ERROR 8684 --- [io-7080-exec-10] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'proc_name' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Please help me resolve
I get the same error even if i use `query.getResultList()`

My stored proc updates the values in the table and expects only one parameter

```
create or replace procedure proc_name(input_id in varchar2)
```

Comment: Have you tried these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199043/ora-06550-line-1-column-7-pls-00201-identifier-payment-update-must-be-decl